# How to use a function for a computer's choice

Tags: python

I am at the final steps of creating a rock, paper, scissors game for class. In our brief we must include a function for the computer's choice.
I created the function but some errors have come up where it says that 'choices' has been undefined. I am new to using functions so I am not entirely sure why these errors have come up as I thought I already defined choices.
This is the piece of code which has the error:

```
def aiChoice():
  choices = ['r', 'p', 's']
  com_choice = random.choice(choices)
# the possible choices
  return choices 
  return com_choice


for i in range(games):
    print(f"Match {i+1}, trust your instinct")
    while True:
        user_play = input("Select r, p, or s: ")
        # asks user to play rock, paper or scissors
        if user_play in choices: **error here that says undefined name 'choices'**
          # checks user input
            break
            # if valid, breaks the loop
        print("Please enter only r, p, or s")
        # otherwise asks again

    com_choice = random.choice(choices) **same error here for 'choices'**
    # assigns the computer choice
    print(com_choice)
    # prints a random item from the list as the computer's choice
    
    if user_play == com_choice:
        print('Draw!')
        draw = draw + 1
        # if the user plays the same move as the computer, one point goes to draw
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message including traceback.

Comment: Please try to produce a minimum reproducible example, by removing the parts of the code that are irrelevant to the problem. See http://sscce.org for guidance.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: You should also try to write less code at a time and *make sure each new piece works* as you go. That way, when you need help, it's obvious *where* the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need choices outside of the aiChoice() function.

See:

```py
import random

win = 0
loss = 0
draw = 0

# the possible choices
choices = ['r', 'p', 's']

def aiChoice():
  com_choice = random.choice(choices)
  return com_choice


while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    # asks user for name
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter characters A-Z only")
    # makes sure user only enters letters
    # taken from Stack Overflow


# asks user how many games they want to play

while True:
  games = int(input(name + ', enter in number of plays between 1 and 7: '))
  if games <= 7:
   break
  else:
    print('1 to 7 only.')
    # makes sure user input doesn't exceed seven plays



for i in range(games):
    print(f"Match {i+1}, trust your instinct")
    while True:
        user_play = input("Select r, p, or s: ")
        # asks user to play rock, paper or scissors
        if user_play in choices:
          # checks user input
            break
            # if valid, breaks the loop
        print("Please enter only r, p, or s")
        # otherwise asks again

    com_choice = random.choice(choices)
    # assigns the computer choice
    print(com_choice)
    # prints a random item from the list as the computer's choice
    
    if user_play == com_choice:
        print('Draw!')
        draw = draw + 1
        # if the user plays the same move as the computer, one point goes to draw
    
    elif user_play == 'r' and com_choice == 'p':
        print('Paper beats rock.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user plays rock and computer plays paper, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 'r' and com_choice == 's':
        print('Rock beats scissors.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays rock and computer plays scissors, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category
    
    elif user_play == 'p' and com_choice == 'r':
        print('Paper beats rock.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays paper and computer plays rock, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category
    
    elif user_play == 'p' and com_choice == 's':
        print('Scissors beats paper.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user playspaper and scissors plays paper, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 's' and com_choice == 'r':
        print('Rock beats scissors.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user plays scissors and computer plays rock, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 's' and com_choice == 'p':
        print('Scissors beats paper.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays scissors and computer plays paper, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category

print(name + "'s final score:")
print('Wins: ' + str(win))
print('Loss: ' + str(loss))
print('Draws: ' + str(draw))
# prints the final score after all games are finished.
```

At the moment you're also not calling the aiChoice() function.

Do this instead:

```py
import random

win = 0
loss = 0
draw = 0

# the possible choices
choices = ['r', 'p', 's']

def aiChoice():
  com_choice = random.choice(choices)
  return com_choice


while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    # asks user for name
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter characters A-Z only")
    # makes sure user only enters letters
    # taken from Stack Overflow


# asks user how many games they want to play

while True:
  games = int(input(name + ', enter in number of plays between 1 and 7: '))
  if games <= 7:
   break
  else:
    print('1 to 7 only.')
    # makes sure user input doesn't exceed seven plays



for i in range(games):
    print(f"Match {i+1}, trust your instinct")
    while True:
        user_play = input("Select r, p, or s: ")
        # asks user to play rock, paper or scissors
        if user_play in choices:
          # checks user input
            break
            # if valid, breaks the loop
        print("Please enter only r, p, or s")
        # otherwise asks again

    com_choice = aiChoice()
    # assigns the computer choice
    print(com_choice)
    # prints a random item from the list as the computer's choice
    
    if user_play == com_choice:
        print('Draw!')
        draw = draw + 1
        # if the user plays the same move as the computer, one point goes to draw
    
    elif user_play == 'r' and com_choice == 'p':
        print('Paper beats rock.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user plays rock and computer plays paper, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 'r' and com_choice == 's':
        print('Rock beats scissors.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays rock and computer plays scissors, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category
    
    elif user_play == 'p' and com_choice == 'r':
        print('Paper beats rock.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays paper and computer plays rock, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category
    
    elif user_play == 'p' and com_choice == 's':
        print('Scissors beats paper.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user playspaper and scissors plays paper, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 's' and com_choice == 'r':
        print('Rock beats scissors.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user plays scissors and computer plays rock, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 's' and com_choice == 'p':
        print('Scissors beats paper.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays scissors and computer plays paper, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category

print(name + "'s final score:")
print('Wins: ' + str(win))
print('Loss: ' + str(loss))
print('Draws: ' + str(draw))
# prints the final score after all games are finished.
```